# How can I get the collection of a custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I am trying to create a custom module in M 2  0.74.0-beta16. How can I can get collection of custom table. I tried
`$this->_mymodulemodelFactory->create()->getCollection();`. The factory file is generated for my module but getCollection() gives noting.

Comment: Anna Völkl's answer working in magento 2.3.1

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to inject the model collection factory into your constructor

```
protected $mymodulemodelFactory;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\ResourceModel\[Entity]\CollectionFactory $mymodulemodelFactory, 
    ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->mymodulemodelFactory = $mymodulemodelFactory;
    ...
}
```

and you can use in any one of the class methods:

```
$collection = $this->mymodulemodelFactory->create();
```

Comment: i tried the same for my custom import for getting the product collection, but when i import the csv, the ajax loading symbol loads indefinitely @Marius

Comment: I want to get the product collection based on the entity id and save those entity ids to my custom table

Answer (score 24):

You need to create **three files** for getting collection from custom module

> 1. Model, 2) ResourceModel, 3) Collection
>
> Namespace: Prince
>
> Module: Hello
>
> Table: hello

**1) Create Hello.php Model file at**

> app/code/Prince/Helloworld/Model/Hello.php

```
<?php
 
namespace Prince\Helloworld\Model;
 
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
 
class Hello extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Define resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Prince\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel\Hello');
    }
}
```

**2) Now create Hello.php ResourceModel at**

> app/code/Prince/Helloworld/Model/ResourceModel/Hello.php

```
<?php
 
namespace Prince\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel;
 
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
 
class Hello extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Define main table
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('hello', 'id'); //hello is table of module
    }
}
```

**3) Now create Collection.php Collection file at**

> app/code/Prince/Helloworld/Model/ResourceModel/Hello/Collection.php

```
<?php
 
namespace Prince\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel\Hello;
 
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
 
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Prince\Helloworld\Model\Hello',
            'Prince\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel\Hello'
        );
    }
}
```

Now you can test your collection in `Index.php` controller `app/code/Prince/Helloworld/Controller/Index/Index.php`

```
<?php
 
namespace Prince\Helloworld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Prince\Helloworld\Model\HelloFactory;
 
class Index extends Action
{
    protected $_modelHelloFactory;
 
    public function __construct(
        Context $context, 
        HelloFactory $modelHelloFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_modelHelloFactory = $modelHelloFactory;
    }
 
    public function execute()
    {
     
        $resultPage = $this->_modelHelloFactory->create();
        $collection = $resultPage->getCollection(); //Get Collection of module data
        var_dump($collection->getData());
        exit;
        
    }
}
```

**If you want to get collection in template using block file**

Another four files you need to add nad create

**1. Block File**

**2. Layout File**

**3. Controller File**

**4. Templarte File**

Create Block file **Hello.php**

```
namespace vendorName\ModuleName\Block\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use vendorName\ModuleName\Model\Hello;

class Hello extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    protected $helloModelFactory;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        Hello $helloModelFactory,
        RequestInterface $request,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_helloModelFactory = $helloModelFactory;
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Preparing global layout
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Display Collection'));
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHello()
    {
        $collection = $this->_helloModelFactory->getCollection();
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Or Create Layout file **routName_controllername_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="vendorName\ModuleName\Block\Event\Index" name="newevent" template="vendorName_ModuleName::Index.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create Controller File **Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace vendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
{
    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     */

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute() {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Create Template file **Index.phtml**

```
<?php

var_dump($block->getgetHello()->getData());
```

I hope it's work for ever

Comment: use Prince\Helloworld\Model\HelloFactory; where is this?

Comment: got it sorry for that

Comment: HOw do i get the full data into a array? 
you are var_dumping the data is there anyway i could get the full data in to array?

Answer (score 1):

try this `$collection = $this->_mymodulemodelFactory->create()`

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a little old thread, but the best solution to get *model* and *collection* with a simple inject:

- make sure, that your Model implements your ModelInterface, and you set the preference for your ModelInterface in di.xml

> `<preference for="Your\Module\Api\Data\ModelInterface" type="Your\Module\Model\Model"/>`

- Inject ModelInterfaceFactory to the constructor

> `protected $_modelFactory;
>    
>    public function __construct(
>       ....
>       \Your\Module\Api\Data\ModelInterfaceFactory $modelFactory,
>       ...
>   )
>   {
>       ...
>       $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
>       ...
>   }`

- and just use anywhere in the class

  for collection:

  > `$collection = $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection();`

  for model:

  > `$model = $this->_modelFactory->create();`