# How to write two queries in one function?

Tags: magento-2.1

In my block file there are some queries like below,

```
    protected $resource;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
    }
public function getFrameColorOption() 
    {
        $tableColor = $resource->getTableName('color_price');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableColor;
        $color = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
        return $color;
    }
public function getGlassPriceOption() 
    {
        $tableGlass = $resource->getTableName('glass_price');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableGlass;
        $glass = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
        return $glass;
    }
```

In there im duplicating my connection how can i do it correctly.

my template .phtml file im retieving those values like below

```
$color = $block->getFrameColorOption();
$glass = $block->getGlassPriceOption();
```

> I need to do this correct way can someone please help me im new to
>   magento

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't use ObjectManager instance directly in files as ECGM2 Magento 2 coding standard, use Factory method**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Myclass extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $resource;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getFrameColorOption() 
    {
        $tableColor = $this->resource->getTableName('color_price');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableColor;
        $color = $this->connection->fetchAll($sql);
        return $color;
    }

    public function getGlassPriceOption() 
    {
        $tableGlass = $this->resource->getTableName('glass_price');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableGlass;
        $glass = $this->connection->fetchAll($sql);
        return $glass;
    }
}
```

Note: Clear var/generation and flush cache.

Comment: it will give error like this - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null

Comment: make sure you first clear var/generation and flush cache

Comment: yeah i have flushed those things

Comment: Post your block code in your question

Comment: I have edit my question

Comment: @Hemal Check my updated answer and let me know if you have any issue

Comment: Can u tell me how to use a model in controller instead of using those type sql quries

Comment: @Hemal, You need to create model class for your custom table to insert, update data. Check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/153936/35758