# Magento 2: How to join product collection to custom table?

Tags: magento2, product-collection, join-table

example: i have a table "table_1" i want to join product collection to get the product data? but I don't know how to join product collection? so everybody can help me pls?

- ### List item

Comment: What join you need and what is relationShip Between Magento product collection & table_1.

Comment: Where you want to join?

Comment: i want get all attribute of product for column controls in my grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this one, you can try it (this is untested):

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$collection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join( array('custom_table'=> 'table_1'), 'custom_table.id = main_table.entity_id', array('custom_table.sku'));
```

Comment: i want get product collection from custom_table. because i use custom_table and get data product from it

Comment: you can check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73908/how-can-i-get-the-collection-of-a-custom-module-in-magento-2